# How do you find a regression for a 3 dimensional output with several 3 dimensional inputs? i.e.

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

I'm a little new to the data analysis game. I'm trying to find a regression between multiple a inputs and one f(a) output. Normally, I would use a simple multivariate analysis for this, but I can't figure out how to do that, seeing that each a and f(a) data point consists of 3 dimensions x, y, and z.

f(a)[a,b,c]= p *a_1[x,y,z] + q * a_2[x,y,z].

I feel like this is probably a pretty simple problem, but after searching the web, I haven't found any solutions.

How would you go about creating this regression?